# Redirect to volume settings in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, mobile, volume

Actually i am developing one application in blackberry. In that application if i click one button it redirects to blackberry mobile volume settings. How can we do that? it supports any  blackberry mobiles. like if i upload my application to any blackberry mobiles. if i click that button in my application. it intents to blackberry volume settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch the phones profile application from within your app with the following. From there you can edit a profile and set the volume.

```
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch("net_rim_bb_profiles_app");
```